# Extract specific token(s) from strings in file and export to other file

Tags: string, powershell

My data file `a.alm` looks like this:

```
2018-05-19  00:26:00,551 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL             CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT1_Reglerfel                  
2018-05-19  00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT41_DV_AL            CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT41_Reglerfel                 
2018-05-19  00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT31_DV_AL            CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT31_Reglerfel                 
2018-05-19  00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT21_DV_AL            CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT21_Reglerfel                 
2018-05-19  00:35:19,627 [LUNSC1  ] U_TA364_GT11_LARM             CFN              LARM      U_TA364_GT11_LARM                      
2018-05-19  00:39:56,135 [LUNSC1  ] U_TA364_GT11_LARM             CFN              LARM      U_TA364_GT11_LARM                      
2018-05-19  00:47:12,612 [LUNSC1  ] U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL              CFN              LARM      U-KB6-GT11 Avvikelselarm
```

I want to extract token 5 and 8 to another file. In my code I read the content of file and loop with a split function.

```
$alarmList = @(Get-Content -Path '.\A.ALM') | foreach {
    $test = $_ -split ' '
    Write-Host $test[6]" "$test[9]
} | Out-File -FilePath '.\Output.txt'
```

Output only gives me the first token though. And I can't get my head around how to correctly print this to a file. Tried replacing `Write-Host` with `File-Output` without any good result.

```
D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL 
D_TA204_GT41_DV_AL 
D_TA204_GT31_DV_AL 
D_TA204_GT21_DV_AL 
U_TA364_GT11_LARM 
U_TA364_GT11_LARM 
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL 
U_FF415_GT46_L_AL 
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL 
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL 
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL
```

I managed this in command line earlier with this script.

```
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%i in (A.alm) do echo %%i >> data.txt
```

But I would like to do it in PowerShell and pipe it on to be able to use the data in a script I already have that counts the occurences.

```
(Select-String -Path '.\data.txt' -Pattern '[^ ]+' -AllMatches).Matches.Value |
    Group-Object -NoElement |
    ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation |
    Out-File -FilePath '.\Statistics.csv'
```

This works good and I understand most of it.

```
    $alarmList = @(Get-Content -Path '.\A.ALM') | foreach { 
    $token = $_ -split ' +'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
         date = $token[0]
         time = $token[1]
         H2   = $token[2]
         H3   = $token[3]
         H4   = $token[4]
         H5   = $token[5]
         H6   = $token[6]
         H7   = $token[7]
         H8   = $token[8]
    }
}
$alarmList | Group H4 -NoElement | Select Name,Count | Out-Gridview
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for /f`counts successive delimiters (default is space) as only one

- to replicate this behaviour use `-split ' +'`

Just to demonstrate the regex based outcome of the `-split` operator:

```
(Get-Content -Path '.\A.ALM') | foreach { 
    $token = $_ -split ' +'
    for ($i=0;$i -le 8;$i++){
        "token[{0}]={1}" -f $i,$token[$i]
    }
}
```

Shorted output of your above a.alm :

```
token[0]=2018-05-19
token[1]=00:47:12,612
token[2]=[LUNSC1
token[3]=]
token[4]=U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL
token[5]=CFN
token[6]=LARM
token[7]=U-KB6-GT11
token[8]=Avvikelselarm
```

To have $alarmList contain all those columns:

```
$alarmList = @(Get-Content -Path '.\A.ALM') | foreach { 
    $token = $_ -split ' +'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
         date = $token[0]
         time = $token[1]
         H2   = $token[2]
         H3   = $token[3]
         H4   = $token[4]
         H5   = $token[5]
         H6   = $token[6]
         H7   = $token[7]
         H8   = $token[8]
    }
}
$alarmList | ft -auto
```

---

```
date       time         H2      H3 H4                 H5  H6   H7                     H8
----       ----         --      -- --                 --  --   --                     --
2018-05-19 00:26:00,551 [LUNSC1 ]  D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL  CFN LARM D_TA204_GT1_Reglerfel
2018-05-19 00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1 ]  D_TA204_GT41_DV_AL CFN LARM D_TA204_GT41_Reglerfel
2018-05-19 00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1 ]  D_TA204_GT31_DV_AL CFN LARM D_TA204_GT31_Reglerfel
2018-05-19 00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1 ]  D_TA204_GT21_DV_AL CFN LARM D_TA204_GT21_Reglerfel
2018-05-19 00:35:19,627 [LUNSC1 ]  U_TA364_GT11_LARM  CFN LARM U_TA364_GT11_LARM
2018-05-19 00:39:56,135 [LUNSC1 ]  U_TA364_GT11_LARM  CFN LARM U_TA364_GT11_LARM
2018-05-19 00:47:12,612 [LUNSC1 ]  U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL   CFN LARM U-KB6-GT11             Avvikelselarm
```

Ofcourse you can further play with it:

```
# $alarmList | Out-Gridview
# $alarmList | Export-csv '.\Output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
$alarmList | Group H4 -NoElement | Select Name,Count
```

---

```
Name               Count
----               -----
D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL      1
D_TA204_GT41_DV_AL     1
D_TA204_GT31_DV_AL     1
D_TA204_GT21_DV_AL     1
U_TA364_GT11_LARM      2
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select an index of the line you want to extract with `Select-Object` and `-Index` parameter and finally store it into `Output.txt` file.

```
$file = Get-Content .\A.ALM
$file | Select-Object -Index 6,9 | Out-File -FilePath '.\Output.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks. I phrased my question a bit unclear. Have tried to clarify it now.